# Java prefix increment operator (++i) result type

Tags: java, types, increment

[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) states:

> If an integer operator other than a shift operator has at least one operand of type `long`, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type `long`. If the other operand is not `long`, it is first widened ([§5.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5)) to type `long` by numeric promotion ([§5.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)).
>
> Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit precision, and the result of the numerical operator is of type `int`. If either operand is not an `int`, it is first widened to type `int` by numeric promotion.

However when I try:

```
byte b = 18;
print(++b);
```

```
static void print(int a) {
    System.out.println("Integer : " + a);
}

static void print(byte a) {
    System.out.println("Byte : " + a);
}
```

The result is:

Byte : 19

I was expecting the method with integer type as input parameter to be called.

The other integer operators like unary plus or unary minus in fact return integer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1 `The type of the prefix increment expression is the type of the variable.`

Comment: @IłyaBursov this comment of yours should really be an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `++` operator does not change the type.

The int literal is of type int.

```
byte b = 1;
b = b + 1; // java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```